# Update statement not updating

Tags: vb.net

HELP!.. when I add an invoice for example 555555.. then when im updating it to 565656 its not updating.. what is the error in my code?

```
If Me.txtInvoice.Tag = 0 Then
     sSQL = "INSERT INTO CollectionTbl (invoice, client, amount, invoice_dated, _
       service, sr_dated, sr, amount_paid, date_paid, period, balance, job, _
       address, tin, render, or_no)"

     sSQL = sSQL & "  VALUES(@invoice, @client, @amount, @invoice_dated, _
       @service, @sr_dated, @sr, @amount_paid, @date_paid, @period, @balance, _
       @job, @address, @tin, @render, @or_no)"

     cmd.CommandText = sSQL
Else
     sSQL = "UPDATE CollectionTbl set  invoice = @invoice, client =  _
       @client, amount =  @amount, invoice_dated = @invoice_dated"
     sSQL = sSQL & " , service = @service, sr_dated = @sr_dated, _
        sr = @sr, amount_paid = @amount_paid, date_paid = @date_paid, _
        period = @period, balance = @balance, job = @job, address = @address, _
        tin = @tin, render = @render, or_no=@or_no where invoice = @invoice"
     cmd.CommandText = sSQL
 End If

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtInvoice.Text)) > 0, Me.txtInvoice.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@client", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtClient.Text)) > 0, Me.txtClient.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtAmount.Text)) > 0, Me.txtAmount.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice_dated", OleDbType.Date).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.dtpCD.Text)) > 0, Me.dtpCD.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@service", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtService.Text)) > 0, Me.txtService.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@sr_dated", OleDbType.Date).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.dtpSR.Text)) > 0, Me.dtpSR.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@sr", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtSr.Text)) > 0, Me.txtSr.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@amount_paid", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtPaid.Text)) > 0, Me.txtPaid.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@date_paid", OleDbType.Date).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.dtpDP.Text)) > 0, Me.dtpDP.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@period", OleDbType.Date).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.dtpPD.Text)) > 0, Me.dtpPD.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@balance", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtBal.Text)) > 0, Me.txtBal.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@job", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtJD.Text)) > 0, Me.txtJD.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@address", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtRich.Text)) > 0, Me.txtRich.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@tin", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtTin.Text)) > 0, Me.txtTin.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@render", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtRender.Text)) > 0, Me.txtRender.Text, DBNull.Value)
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@or_no", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Len(Trim(Me.txtOR.Text)) > 0, Me.txtOR.Text, DBNull.Value)

  cmd.Parameters.Add("@invoice", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = Me.txtInvoice.Text
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

  'If the record is new then we have to get its ID so that 
  'we can edit it rightaway after the insertion.
If Me.txtInvoice.Tag = 0 Then
    cmd.CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
           'Set textbox tag property with the ID of new record
    Me.txtInvoice.Tag = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
End If
MsgBox("Data has been save.")
```

Answer (score 0):

it will not update because if you will update an invoice of 55555 into 55565 (or whatsoever), what happens in the query will be

`UPDATE tablename SET invoice = 55565 WHERE invoice = 55565`   -- > I assume there's no invoice that's 55565 yet, so no update will happen.

The solution is to get the value for the invoice that you want to update first (that's 55555 in my example, @invoice) and store a different value for the one that you would want to update (that's 55565 in the example,  @invoice2)

**EDIT**

In your example, you said that you added an invoice of 555555. Therefore your table CollectionTbl now has an invoice of 555555

```
CollectionTbl
invoice | client | etc... |
____________________________
555555  | exmple | etc... |
```

Now, you want to update invoice 555555 to 565656 right? 
What you did is

```
UPDATE CollectionTbl set  invoice = @invoice etc... WHERE invoice = @invoice
```

your `@invoice` here is equal to 565656

looking back at CollectionTbl, you cannot see an invoice of 565656, only 555555. Therefore you can't update it. All you have to do is to get the invoice that you added on CollectionTbl, that's 555555, then use it on your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i dont seem to understant because im new to vb.net.. can u post a complete example based on mine? tnx

Comment: the error lies in your WHERE clause, you have to specify the invoice that you want to update.

Comment: the error lies in your WHERE clause, you have to specify the invoice that you want to update. The parameter invoice in your 'WHERE invoice = @invoice' clause should be the invoice that you want to update (ex. 555555), not the invoice that you want to update it to (565656).

Comment: now i get it.. i use  where invoice  like '%" & Me.txtInvoice.Tag & "%'".. and it work.. is it ok?

Comment: have you tried doing `WHERE invoice = '" & Me.txtInvoice.Tag & "` ??
Mark this as answered if it is already solved :))

Comment: Actually, if you have an invoice of 555, 55, 5555 and you want to update invoice 565656 to 5, all invoice with '5' in it will be updated if you use LIKE % %, so try changing it to `WHERE invoice = '" & Me.txtInvoice.Tag & "'` instead